# How to store the values of a set distinct subsets using dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

How could I use a list or tuple as a key for a dictionary in Python? Let us suppose I have a set of subsets as `L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 19]`. Now I want store a value for each subset. How could I handle this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is, to convert the individual elements as the key.

Example:

```
{"".join(map(str, x)): x for x in L}
```

This would give an output of

```
{'123': [1, 2, 3], '45': [4, 5], '619': [6, 19]}
```

for your example

Note that it is not the most efficient way to go about.